# How to select only first three elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select only first three *elements* with the `:nth-child()` *selector*?

```css
section > figure:nth-child( ? ) {
  /* ... */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>1</figure> <!-- select this -->
  <figure>2</figure> <!-- and this -->
  <figure>3</figure> <!-- and this -->
  <figure>4</figure>
  <figure>5</figure>
  <figure>6</figure>
</section>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
section > figure:nth-child(-n+3) {background: Aqua}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>1</figure>
  <figure>2</figure>
  <figure>3</figure>
  <figure>4</figure>
  <figure>5</figure>
  <figure>6</figure>
</section>
```

Comment: I love this solution. For the curious minds among us I looked how it works - it is a simple formula to return 3, 2 and 1: 
-0+3 = 3,  
-1+3 = 2,  
-2+3 = 1.

Comment: Just to add to LaZza's explanation, for numbers greater than 3, the return value is negative... and you can't have a child with a negative index.